# Sass: rgba function is not working as per documentation

Tags: sass

I have two examples that I'm trying to solve:

**Example 1**

```
$test: #101E41

body
    --colors-dim: rgba(#{$test}, 0.64)
```

**Output:** `rgba(#101E41, 0.64)`

---

**Example 2**

```
body
    --colors-active: #101E41
    --colors-dim: rgba(var(--colors-active), 0.64)
```

**Output:** `rgba(var(--colors-active), 0.64)`

Both of these look like are examples that should be valid as shown here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules#rgb

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [make use of interpolation to use Sass inside CSS Custom Properties](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/declarations#custom-properties)

> CSS custom properties, also known as CSS variables, have an unusual declaration syntax: they allow almost any text at all in their declaration values. What’s more, those values are accessible to JavaScript, so any value might potentially be relevant to the user. This includes values that would normally be parsed as SassScript.
>
> Because of this, Sass parses custom property declarations differently than other property declarations. **All tokens, including those that look like SassScript, are passed through to CSS as-is**. The only exception is interpolation, which is the only way to inject dynamic values into a custom property.

```
$bar: #900;

:root {
  --foo: #{rgba($bar, 0.5)};
}
```

Results in:

```css
:root {
  --foo: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

---

For your second example, you're going to have to get a little... creative... since Sass will bail and ignore any CSS Custom Property syntax it sees, you can't make use of Sass's `rgba` function with Custom Properties - the Sass compiler won't resolve the values for you.

Thankfully, you can still use [the native CSS `rgba` function](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#rgba-color) with Custom Properties, the only downside is that you'll need to break your hexadecimal value into its `R`, `G`, and `B` values.

```
@function toRGB($color)
  @return red($color), green($color), blue($color)

$bar: #900

:root
  --foo: #{$bar}
  --foo-rgb: #{toRGB($bar)}

  --foo-dim: #{rgba($bar, 0.5)}
  --foo-dim: rgba(var(--foo-rgb), 0.5)
  
.button
  background-color: var(--foo-dim)
```

Compiles to:

```css
:root {
  --foo: #900;
  --foo-rgb: 153, 0, 0;
  --foo-dim: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.5);
  --foo-dim: rgba(var(--foo-rgb), 0.5);
}

.button {
  background-color: var(--foo-dim);
}
```

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/39ffc57c492de73066831afe5a9696f6

Comment: Hi Coogan, thank you for the explanation! this looks like it works for variables but still not working for `var()` (Example 2 in my question)

Comment: Hey @bryan, you're right - I've updated with extra detail

Comment: This all "looks" good Coogan! But for some reason, I'm not getting the same output as you. I've linked what I'm doing with what is exported [here](https://i.imgur.com/wySpNkd.png) -- (Note: I'm using SASS not SCSS)

Comment: I've updated to use the Sass syntax instead of SCSS - I did notice an error in my previous example (I wasn't interpolating `--foo: $bar` )

I've also added a link to a SassMeister gist to show it working as expected